# GATC Campaign Tracking Methods not getting tracked in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

so Im looking to someone can confirm if Im setting GA code correctly. I need to change the names from the utm parameters that come by default in analytics. Im trying to set the campaign tracking, however when checking the analytics the campaign called "web" is not displaying in Acquisition > Campaigns. Im using the url like this:
http://example.com/?source=ad&medium=1&web=mydomain

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
pageTracker._setCampNameKey("web");
pageTracker._setCampMediumKey("medium");
pageTracker._setCampSourceKey("source");
```

Is it something wrong with it? should I use Asinc snippet instead? Can't I use the 3 at same time, without using the utm_source?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong, you are mixing up syntaxes for analytics.js and ga.js.

analytics.js is the latest version aka Universal Analytics. But unfortunately it doesnt have a direct method to redefine campaign names as you do with Classic Analytics.

### Manual Approach

One option you have is parsing these new parameters yourself and just passing to analytics their values using [campaignName](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#campaignName), campaignSource and campaignMedium parameters. It also has to be done before you send the pageview.

Your code would look something like this.

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx', 'auto');
if (cusomtParameterInURL()) {
  var cn = parseUrlParameter("web");
  ga('set', 'campaignName', cn);
}
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Where:

- `cusomtParameterInURL` is a function that returns true if you have the parameters in the url; AND
- `parseUrlParameter` is a function that parses url parameters from the URL.

### Plugin approach

Luckily Google provides a custom [plugin as an example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/plugins#) that implements exactly the functionality described above. Plugins are a clean way to extend Google Analytics functionality.

1. Copy the plugin [campaign-loader.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/plugins#) and upload to your site.
2. Include the plugin on your site.

   ```
   ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
   ga('require', 'campaignLoader', {
     debug: false,
     nameParam: 'web',
     sourceParam: 'source',
     mediumParam: 'medium'
   });
   ga('campaignLoader:loadCampaignFields');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
   ```

Comment: Hi Eduardo, thanks for your answers, I tried with both methods but now analytics doesn't seem to be tracking the site. I'm trying to check codes but Im not able to see what is wrong, for instance with manual approach. I tried with plugin but Im not sure if the campaign-loader.js is correct either, this only seems to be working normally if I put ga('send', 'pageview'); right after the first line, but I think this way this is not tracking the parameters. Please advise, thank you.

Comment: If Analytics is not tracing you are not including the plugin correctly. When you run `ga('require', 'campaignLoader')` analytics will stop processing further commands until the plugin is loaded and the `ga('provide', 'campaignLoader', ...)` is run. So probably that line is not running. Make sure your plugin is included. If the file is correctly included you should see the plugin inside the object `window.gaplugins`